# Get response if text inserted

Tags: php

I'm trying to add a switch to `ms_data['text']` in case user types some words in chat, but its not working,

Can someone help me solve that?

```
function RegisterMessage($ms_data = array()) {
    global $wo, $sqlConnect;
    if ($wo['loggedin'] == false) {
        return false;
    }
    if (empty($ms_data)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (empty($ms_data['text']) || !isset($ms_data['text']) || strlen($ms_data['text']) < 0) {
        if (empty($ms_data['media']) || !isset($ms_data['media']) || strlen($ms_data['media']) < 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    if (isset($ms_data['text'])) {
    switch ($ms_data['text']]) {
        case '1':
            echo "one";
            break;
        case '2':
            echo "two";
            break;
        case '3':
            echo "three";
            break;
        }
    }

    $fields = '`' . implode('`, `', array_keys($ms_data)) . '`';
    $data   = '\'' . implode('\', \'', $ms_data) . '\'';
    $query  = mysqli_query($sqlConnect, " INSERT INTO " . T_MESSAGES . " ({$fields}) VALUES ({$data})");
    if ($query) {
        $message_id = mysqli_insert_id($sqlConnect);
        return $message_id;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: there are at least two bad issues with your code: 1) you're using globals (we can't know if some of these globals are already used, you should pass variables to functions, you should use globals only in small scripts 2) you should encapsulate your database access to some class, no raw mysqli* queries. 3) `strlen($ms_data['text']) < 0)` what? strlen of anything can't be < 0 4) learn to use var_dump($variable) to debug something

Comment: @strangeqargo i've deleted part of the code, everything on the code of the chat is working good, i just want to add the "case" so for example, if the user write !help he will receive echo. Thank you for your answer

Comment: You shouldn't echo the words you want to replace. Just replace them e.g. `$ms_data = preg_replace('/1\b/i', 'one', $ms_data);`

Answer (score 1):

Your switch is not working because you have and extra ']':

replace:

```
switch ($ms_data['text']]) {
```

by:

```
switch ($ms_data['text']) {
```